# How to convert total time into minutes for custom audio player?

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, dom-events

I currently have a well working audio player that shows the current time over total time.

```
<audio id="audioPlayer" 
    preload="true" 
    ontimeupdate="document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = Math.floor(this.currentTime) + ' / ' + Math.floor(this.duration);">
    <source src="oh-my.mp3">      
</audio>


<div id="wrapper">
    <!--Audio Player Interface-->
    <div id="audioplayer">
        <button id="pButton" class="play" onclick="document.getElementById('audioplayer').play();"></button>
        <div id="timeline">
            <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
            <div id="playhead"></div>
        <span id="tracktime">0 / 0</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Although the issue is that it is shown in seconds and not minutes for example: 222 / 342. I am wondering how to convert the current time and total time into minutes, I assume suing something with math.Floor. 
Link to my [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/tunechest000/1cgs9ewy/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grab minutes:
`Math.floor(this.currentTime / 60 )`

I would advice creating the formatTime function (because you will be using it at least two times):

```
function formatTime( time ) {
  let minutes = Math.floor( time / 60 )
  let timeForSeconds = time - ( minutes * 60 ) // seconds without counted minutes 
  let seconds = Math.floor( timeForSeconds )
  let secondsReadable = seconds > 9 ? seconds : `0${seconds}` // To change 2:2 into 2:02
  return `${minutes}:${secondsReadable}`
}
```

Then you can swap it: `ontimeupdate="document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = formatTime( this.currentTime ) + ' / ' + formatTime( this.duration );">`

Comment: I tried adding those lines off code and it didn't work, would you be able to show me where to add the  code in fiddle.

Comment: it just stays at 0/0 the whole time

Comment: 0/0 appears when formatTime is not defined or definded in the wrong place (for example in function). https://jsfiddle.net/k09ydn2u/1/

Comment: Thank you so much!! When I click on a song for a quick second the total time time appears NaN 0:NaN how do I fix  that?

Comment: Duration for ontimeupdate event returns NaN (not a number). You can fix it with `time = isNaN( time ) ? 0 : time` in the first line of formatTime function. It swaps NaN to 0 and change it later to 0:00.

Comment: I just added that and it didn't work any other ideas?